# jQuery Keep a popup from going off the bottom of the screen

Tags: jquery

I have gallery of images in a grid. When you hover on an image a larger one appears in a hovering div called .popup. I need to keep this popup from showing off screen when the user hovers over an image close to the bottom of the visible browser window. Here is the html

```
        <li>
            <div class="inner">
                <img src="photos/photo.jpg">
                <div class="subcat-image-name">
                    photo
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup">
                <img src="photos/photo.jpg">
                <div class="popup-text">
                    some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

The .popup div is set to visibility:hidden and then visibility:visible on hover over the image. Here is my jQuery to keep the popup on screen, but I can't get it to do anything:

```
$('.popup').bind('visibility:visible', function(event) {
     w = $(window).height();
     var position = $(this).position();
     var distancefrombottom = w - position.top;
     if ( distancefrombottom < 500 ) {
         $(this).css('bottom','20px');
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `position:fixed` for class `popup`. This make your popup display in same position wherever you scroll the page.

```
 .popup{
     position: fixed
 }
```